# Blinking divs like traffic lights?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this website: [backlinkbeat.com](http://backlinkbeat.com). To the down, there are 3 divs having the background images. Each background-image includes a number like "1", "2", "3". I want those divs to blink as traffic lights respectively.

The script I wrote is not blinking the lights correctly as you can see in the [link](http://backlinkbeat.com) which means that it is not blinking the correct order. I want to blink them in the way are shown in the markup:

```
<div style="float:left; height:400px;">
    <div style=" margin-top:50px;">
        <div class="list cufon one" id="blink1" style="width:420px;">put you on just any, <span style="color:#1fbfd1;">www.yourwebsite.com</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list cufon two" id="blink2" style="width:420px;">Press <span style="color:#1fbfd1;">"do it"</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list cufon three" id="blink3" style="width:420px;">see the backlinks <span style="color:#1fbfd1;">roll in!</span>
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

The script I wrote which donot work correctly is:

```
setInterval(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
       var vis1 = $("#blink1").css("visibility");
       vis1 = (!vis1 || vis1 == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
       $("#blink1").css("visibility", vis1);
        }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
setInterval(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
       var vis2 = $("#blink2").css("visibility");
       vis2 = (!vis2 || vis2 == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
       $("#blink2").css("visibility", vis2);
    }, 2000);
}, 2000);
setInterval(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
       var vis3 = $("#blink3").css("visibility");
       vis3 = (!vis3 || vis3 == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
       $("#blink3").css("visibility", vis3);
    }, 3000);
}, 3000);
```

Thanks,
Areeb

Comment: Could you add some markup to make it a repro? Also, tell us *what* isn't working correctly and what you've tried so far and why your solutions didn't work.

Comment: What does "do not work correctly" mean? Does the page fail to load? Do the lights appear but in the wrong order? Do they appear, but do not blink? Do they blink but never come back on? You need to be specific in what the behavior you're experiencing is, and what the behavior you expect to experience is. Think about the information you would need to debug an issue in a completely foreign code base.

Comment: @ChrisHayes not in the correct order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you give your elements a common class, ex:

```
<div class="blink">One</div>
<div class="blink">Two</div>
<div class="blink">Three</div>
```

Then you can simplify your code to:

```
//Cache element collection and keep a reference to the visible element 
var $elements = $('.blink').css('visibility','hidden'),
    $visible = $elements.first().css('visibility','visible');

//Single interval function to handle blinking
setInterval(function(){
    //Hide visible element
    $visible.css('visibility','hidden');
    //Find next one
    var $next = $visible.next('.blink');
    if(!$next.length)
        $next = $elements.first();
    //Show next element
    $visible = $next.css('visibility','visible');
},1000);
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/7uvkQ/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/andaywells/eQuXn/15/
I have modified this code: http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/pdsu7/5/
So that each div stays in position, the 'hold' div keeps it there.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var delay = 5000,
    fade = 500;
var banners = $('.banner');
var len = banners.length;
var i = 0;

setTimeout(cycle, delay);

function cycle() {
    $(banners[i % len]).fadeOut(fade, function () {
        $(banners[++i % len]).fadeIn(fade, function () {
            setTimeout(cycle, delay);
        });
    });
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this example will help you.

CSS

```
.lamp {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
}
.lampRed {
    background-color: red;
}
.lampYellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.lampGreen {
    background-color: green;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="trafficLight">
    <div>Click to Start and Stop</div>
    <div class="lamp" id="Red"></div>
    <div class="lamp" id="Yellow"></div>
    <div class="lamp" id="Green"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var changeState = (function () {
    var state = 0,
        lamps = ["Red", "Yellow", "Green"],
        lampsLength = lamps.length,
        order = [
            [5000, "Red"],
            [3000, "Red", "Yellow"],
            [5000, "Green"],
            [3000, "Yellow"]
        ],
        orderLength = order.length,
        lampIndex,
        orderIndex,
        sId;

    return function (stop) {
        if (stop) {
            clearTimeout(sId);
            return;
        }

        var lamp,
        lampDOM;

        for (lampIndex = 0; lampIndex < lampsLength; lampIndex += 1) {
            lamp = lamps[lampIndex];
            lampDOM = document.getElementById(lamp);
            if (order[state].indexOf(lamp) !== -1) {
                lampDOM.classList.add("lamp" + lamp);
            } else {
                lampDOM.classList.remove("lamp" + lamp);
            }
        }

        sId = setTimeout(changeState, order[state][0]);
        state += 1;
        if (state >= orderLength) {
            state = 0;
        }
    };
}());

document.getElementById("trafficLight").addEventListener("click", (function () {
    var state = false;

    return function () {
        changeState(state);
        state = !state;
    };
}()), false);
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/n6LgZ/)</kbd>